# How to prevent output folder from being showed as possible target (autocomplete)

Tags: makefile, g++, project, lib, project-layout

I've created a small project with the following file structure:

```
.
+---include
    +---StringUtils.h
    +---Utils.h
+---src
    +---StringUtils.cpp
    +---Utils.h
+---bin
    +---libutils.so
Makefile
```

*bin/libutils.so* is built with `make` (both the folder and the *.so* are created within the makefile), and *Makefile* looks as follows:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := target

LIB_NAME := log

SRC_DIR := src
INC_DIR := include
BIN_DIR := bin

INSTALL_INC_DIR := /usr/local/include/$(LIB_NAME)
INSTALL_LIB_DIR := /usr/local/lib

SOURCES := $(addprefix $(SRC_DIR)/,*.cpp)
OBJ_NAME := $(addsuffix $(addprefix $(LIB_NAME),.so),lib)

TARGET_OBJ := $(BIN_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)
TARGET_INCS := $(INC_DIR)/*.h

DBG := 0

INC_FLAGS := $(addsuffix $(INC_DIR),-I)
CXX_VER_FLAG := -std=c++17
DBG_FLAG := -ggdb3

CXXFLAGS := $(CXX_VER_FLAG) $(INC_FLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += -shared -fPIC

ifeq ($(DBG),1)
CXXFLAGS := -ggdb3 $(CXXFLAGS)
endif

.PHONY: all target clean install uninstall reinstall

all: target install

target: $(TARGET_OBJ)

$(TARGET_OBJ): $(BIN_DIR)/%.so: $(SOURCES)
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN_DIR)

install: target
    sudo install -d $(INSTALL_LIB_DIR)
    sudo install -d $(INSTALL_INC_DIR)
    sudo install -m644 $(TARGET_OBJ) $(INSTALL_LIB_DIR)
    sudo install -m644 $(TARGET_INCS) $(INSTALL_INC_DIR)
    sudo ldconfig

uninstall:
    sudo $(RM) $(INSTALL_LIB_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)
    sudo $(RM) -r $(INSTALL_INC_DIR)
    sudo ldconfig

reinstall: uninstall install
```

My issue is that when inside the project folder, the `make` autocomplete also displays the `bin/` folder as a possible target:

```
....../libs/libutils$ make 
all        bin/       clean      install    reinstall  target     uninstall
```

I suppose the solution would be to remove `$(BIN_DIR)` from `TARGET_OBJ := $(BIN_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)`, but I'm not exactly sure how to make that work.

Also, any constructive criticism regarding the entire *Makefile* is much appreciated.

Comment: make doesn't provide command autocompletion facilities.  That is some kind of add-on for your shell (bash or zsh or whatever).  You'll have to find out where it comes from and ask the people involved with creating it, how it works / how it determines what targets to suggest for completion.

Comment: I don't have much comment on your makefile.  I do wonder why you are using the very complicated `$(addsuffix $(addprefix $(LIB_NAME),.so),lib)` instead of just writing `lib$(LIB_NAME).so` ?

Comment: That is true, I've used this complicated syntax mostly for learning purposes.